# running jquery media query without reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have three different divs red, blue, green and yellow. red contains an input box. am trying to hide yellow if the input box in red is clicked(focus) and if the screen size is below 500. it does work but only if i reload the page is there any way to make it work without reloading the page?

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input class="s" placeholder="Search">
</form>
</div>
<div class="blue"> top </div>
<div class="green"> middle </div>
<div class="yellow"> bottom </div>
```

js

```
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
   $(function(){

   $(".s").on("focus",function()
   {
        $(".yellow").hide();
   });
   $(".s").on("blur",function()
   {
        $(".yellow").show();
   });

});
}
else {
}
```

css

```
    .red, .blue, .green, .yellow
{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
.red{
    background: red;
}
.blue{
    background: blue;
}
.green{
    background: green;
}
.yellow{
    background: yellow;
}
.s:focus{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.s:focus + yellow{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: On focus you should call a function which checks the window width and then hide accordingly

Comment: am a noob. don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you want can be done using a much simple way, here is my HTML

HTML

```
        <div class="red">
            <form>
                <input type="text" class="s" id="txt" placeholder="Search"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="blue">top</div>
        <div class="green">middle</div>
        <div class="yellow">bottom</div>
```

CSS

```
            .red, .blue, .green, .yellow {
                padding: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #f00;
            }
            .red {
                background: red;
            }
            .blue {
                background: blue;
            }
            .green {
                background: green;
            }
            .yellow {
                background: yellow;
            }
            .s:focus {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            .s:focus + yellow {
                display: none;
            }
```

MY JS:

```
              $(document).ready(function() {
                var width = $(window).width();
               $(window).resize(function() {
                    $(".s").trigger("blur");
                    $(".s").on("focus", function()
                    {
                        var width = $(window).width();
                        if (width < 960)
                        {

                            $(".yellow").hide();
                        }
                    });
                    $(".s").on("blur", function()
                    {
                        $(".yellow").show();
                    });
               });
            });
```

UPDATED JS:

```
                $(document).ready(function() {
                var width = $(window).width();
                   $(".s").trigger("blur");
                    $(".s").on("focus", function()
                    {
                        var width = $(window).width();
                        $("#det").text(width);
                        alert(width);
                        if (width < 960)
                        {
                       $(".yellow").hide();
                        }
                    });
                    $(".s").on("blur", function()
                    {
                        $(".yellow").show();
                    });
               $(window).resize(function() {
                    $(".s").trigger("blur");
                    $(".s").on("focus", function()
                    {
                        var width = $(window).width();
                        $("#det").text(width);
                        alert(width);
                        if (width < 960)
                        {
                         $(".yellow").hide();
                        }
                    });
                    $(".s").on("blur", function()
                    {
                        $(".yellow").show();
                    });
               });
            });
```

What i am doing here is ,

1. Used `window.resize()`function in order to detect the resize of the page
2. Once window is resized, i trigger a blur function to the textbox, using `$(".s").trigger("blur")`
3. Then, I find the width of the window, only when the user focuses on the text
4. Once input box gets into focus again, I hide the Yellow div.

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/vengatesh/nopg8y34/) for your reference

Comment: works if i loaded the page already then resize. but if i resize then reload it doesn't

Answer (score 3):

Instead of binding on load of the page, put the code in a function and call that function when you want it to be called. I added it in a function and called on click of a button for the demo.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vg0zbu28/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('button').on('click', function () {
    if (checkWidth()) { //checking width of window before binding the focus event
        onFocusHandling();  
    }
 });
});


function onFocusHandling() {
 //you can also add the checkWidth() here than above
 $(".s").on("focus", function () {
    $('.yellow').hide();
 });

 $(".s").on("blur", function () {
    $('.yellow').show();
 });
}

function checkWidth() {
 return ($(window).width() < 960);
}
```

**Updated**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vg0zbu28/7/)

Called the function `onFocusHandling` on window resize and on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 onFocusHandling();
 $(window).resize(function () {
    onFocusHandling();
 });
});

function onFocusHandling() {

  if (checkWidth()) {
    $(".s").on("focus", function () {
        $('.yellow').hide();
    });
    $(".s").on("blur", function () {
        $('.yellow').show();
    });
  }
  else {
   $(".s").off("focus").off("blur");        
  }
}
```

When the width is maximized unbind the focus and blur event.

Comment: can it work without the bind button? like can i just work on focus without clicking the bind button

Comment: Yes. I have used it on button for the demo. You can call onFocusHandling whenever you need it. When do you want it to be called?

Comment: i wasn't lying when i said am a noob

Comment: From your comment to another answer it seems you needed the function to be called on when you resize the browser. Call `onFocusHandling`on `$(window).resize`(as other answer suggested) and also call it on `document.ready()`. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vg0zbu28/5/)

Comment: actually i want the yellow to be hidden ONLY when the width is bellow. cant it work like that? it works on below and if maximized it still goes hidden

Comment: Updated the fiddle and edited the answer. I remove the binding when  maximised via off(see else)